# How to convert IntelliJ IDEA GUI designer files from binary to source

Tags: intellij-idea

The designer can generate GUI into either binary class files or Java source code.
All my forms were created using the binary setting, but now I need everything to generate as Java source.

How can I convert the existing forms?

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gui-designer.html